# Google Data Studio Geo map Invalid Field for Zoom Area

Tags: looker-studio

I'm using `Google Data Studio` to track sales. I'm trying to utilizes the Geo Map to show the locations of "active" clients ( I have established a filter for active clients already).

I'm using `City` as the `Dimension` and `Total sales` as the metric. However, my Zoom Area option just show "Invalid Field" and doesn't let me change to anything else.

I have a `Country Code`, `Region Code`, `City`, `State fields` for location. I don't have a Zip Code location.

How do I changed by Zoom Area to Zoom in on the Country of a particular Country Code?

Comment: Are you simply coming up against GDS mapping's general uselessness when it gets outside the US? I fear you may be. e.g. you may need to leave the State out for some countries (it doesn't work for the UK for example).

Comment: 95% of my locations are in the US. I saw it's hit or miss outside the US but I don't see why having a few outside the US would invalidate the rest.

Comment: Where is the Total Sales metric sourced from? I can't see it listed as an option in my report. Maybe try changing the metric - perhaps it is not possible to use the geolocation dimensions and this metric at the same time.

Comment: I figured this out. The metric was fine but the Dimension I used was not, well the dimension was okay but the type of format I had the dimension listed under wasn't. I had to change the Dimension to a GEO field type instead of Text. Seems so simple know that I know why it wasn't working. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the data type of your fields to Geo data types respectively (like if you have a text field Country representing Country then change this to Geo data type Country) on your source.
Go to "Resource > Manage added data sources > Edit" and change the data type of the field.